# Flip, mirror image in IE8 - CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, flip

As above how can i flip image in IE8.

```
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

This works fine but not in IE8

Comment: ie8 doesnt support css3, u have to use polyfil. for example http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Comment: CSSSandpaper polyfill may help with this, but top be honest there are times when you just have to accept that IE8 is an old browser and doesn't have features like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter:fliph` should work in IE4-8, even without `-ms-` prefix (which was needed only for early beta versions of IE8). Probably you should add parentheses `filter:fliph()` as [this demo](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/overview/FiltWzrd.htm) suggests. You can also try the newer IE5.5-9 syntax — `filter: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1)` (as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) recommends).

Older IE versions required the element to have layout to apply filters to it (how to make an element have layout, is described ), but, AFAIK, IE8 doesn't require it.